# How to flat json in android

Tags: java, android, json

I have json

```
{
  "a": 11,
  "b": 22,
  "object": {
    "c": 33,
    "d": 44,
    "e": 55
  }
}
```

and i would like to made a json with just one level, that contains all the keys like this:

```
{
  "a": 11,
  "b": 22,
  "c": 33,
  "d": 44,
  "e": 55
}
```

Can be assumed That the keys are not duplicated in my json!

what is the fast way to do that in android?

Comment: Can inner object have same key as outer one? Can there be more than one object of same type like `{a:{x:y},b:{x:z}}` (if yes then how would you want to convert it)?

Comment: you right, i forgot to write this. duplicate keys are imposible

Comment: I suppose you need code but don´t have a single line...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String json = "{
  "a": 11,
  "b": 22,
  "object": {
    "c": 33,
    "d": 44,
    "e": 55
  }
}";


JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
JSONObject jObjNew = new JSONObject();
multiToLinearJson(jObj);


public void multiToLinearJson(JSONObject jObj) {
    Iterator<String> iter = jObj.keys();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String key = iter.next();
        try {
            Object value = jObj.get(key);
            if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                multiToLinearJson(value);
            }
            jObjNew.put(key, value);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // Something went wrong!
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
    jObjNew.toString();

```
{
  "a": 11,
  "b": 22,
  "c": 33,
  "d": 44,
  "e": 55
}
```

Not tested!

Comment: your answer was true, and shortly, but i preffer to code it a little different because my code circumstances. thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers,
Actually i have done it by code

```
// Iterate inner-json and add to the outer json
JSONObject innerJson = outerJson.getJSONObject("Object");
Iterator<?> keys = innerJson .keys();
while( keys.hasNext() ){
    String key = (String)keys.next();
    Object ob = innerJson .get(key);
    outerJson.put(key, ob);
}
```